# c++ fetching web page using wininet

Tags: c++, web-scraping, wininet

I'm trying to download a web page using WinInet. I've used the code given here: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/windows/109799/

It mostly works, but there seems to be some encoding issue that I have no idea how to fix.

For instance, this line (using [www.stackoverflow.com](http://www.stackoverflow.com) as an example page):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Shared/stacks.css?v=48511da708b8">
```

Is returned as this line:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Shared/stacks.css?cks.css?ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌðA6÷v=48511da708b8">
```

(for the sake of not spamming, I've actually removed most of the special characters)

Comment: That code passes an unterminated buffer to `std::cout`. What you are seeing is the garbage in the buffer after the text until a 0 terminator is found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code:

```
while(InternetReadFile(OpenAddress, DataReceived, 4096, &NumberOfBytesRead) && NumberOfBytesRead )
{
    cout << DataReceived;
}
```

`DataReceived` is receiving arbitrary bytes. It is not a null-terminated string, but the code is passing it to the `operator<<` overload that expects a null-terminated string. So the printing is exceeding the end of the received data, printing bytes from surrounding memory, until a random `0x00` byte is encountered.

Use the `istream::write()` method instead, so that you can tell it exactly how many characters to print:

```
cout.write(DataReceived, NumberOfBytesRead);
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know cout.write() even existed. It seems the same syntax applies for file outputs, so that's great.